# JavaScript Ajax save result

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having a problem. I'm trying do ajax on my own, but I have problem with saving result from ajax call. I want it to do just like jQuery does, or similarly.
So, I have a function called ajax, with I parameter, and this parameter is an object with properties like: method, url, async, data, and success ...
When I call ajax function, I have no problem except success .. I want it just like jQuery (dont ask me why I dont want to use jQ). So I want this

```
ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    async: false,
    data: "name=something",
    success: function(result) {
         console.log(result);
    }
});
```

and I have a problem to save result to parameter in definition of ajax function, and here just use it.

Here's ajax.php

```php
<?php
  $name = "The input is: " . $_POST['name'];
  return $name;
?>
```

Here's a definition of an ajax function:

```
var ajax = function (arg) {
    if (typeof arg.method !== "undefined" && typeof arg.url !== "undefined" && typeof arg.async !== "undefined" 
        && typeof arg.success !== "undefined" && typeof arg.data !== "undefined") {

        var xmlhttp, i = 0,
        versions = [
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0",   
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",  
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",   
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",  
            "Microsoft.XmlHttp"
        ];

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            for ( ; i < versions.length; i++) {
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]); break;
                } catch (e) { }
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    /* ////////////////////////////////////////////
                                  HERE I HAVE PROBLEM
                     /////////////////////////////////////////////*/

                     // this is obviously wrong (I know it is)
                     arg.success = function (something) {
                           something = xmlhttp.responseText;
                     }
                } else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                    console.log("There was an error 400");
                } else {
                    console.log("UNSUCCESSFUL");
                }
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open(arg.method, arg.url, arg.async);
        xmlhttp.send(arg.data);
        console.log("Method: " + arg.method + "\nURL: " + arg.url + "\nAsync: " + arg.async + "\nData: " + arg.data + "\n");
    }
};
```

How to save a `xmlhttp.responseText` to `arg.success` function parameter in a  way that I can use the parameter in ajax function calls? Should I use callbacks?

EDIT: Thanks, it works but, it only print "The input is: ". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You want to call the method, not set it.

```
arg.success(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ajax = function (arg) {
    if (typeof arg.method !== "undefined" && typeof arg.url !== "undefined" && typeof arg.async !== "undefined" 
        && typeof arg.success !== "undefined" && typeof arg.data !== "undefined") {

        var xmlhttp, i = 0,
        versions = [
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0",   
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",  
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",   
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",  
            "Microsoft.XmlHttp"
        ];

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            for ( ; i < versions.length; i++) {
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]); break;
                } catch (e) { }
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    arg.success(xmlhttp.responseText);
                } else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                    console.log("There was an error 400");
                } else {
                    console.log("UNSUCCESSFUL");
                }
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open(arg.method, arg.url, arg.async);
        xmlhttp.send(arg.data);
        console.log("Method: " + arg.method + "\nURL: " + arg.url + "\nAsync: " + arg.async + "\nData: " + arg.data + "\n");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got **status 200** and there is some **data** that is from **server**.

**With callback**: If need someting to return you can use callback.

```
var ajax = function (arg) {
    if (typeof arg.method !== "undefined" && typeof arg.url !== "undefined" && typeof arg.async !== "undefined" 
        && typeof arg.success !== "undefined" && typeof arg.data !== "undefined") {
        var xmlhttp, i = 0,
        versions = [
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0",   
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",  
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",   
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",  
            "Microsoft.XmlHttp"
        ];

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            for ( ; i < versions.length; i++) {
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]); break;
                } catch (e) { }
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var Success = function (xmlhttp.responseText);
                    alert(Success); 
                } else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                    console.log("There was an error 400");
                } else {
                    console.log("UNSUCCESSFUL");
                }
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open(arg.method, arg.url, arg.async);
        xmlhttp.send(arg.data);
        console.log("Method: " + arg.method + "\nURL: " + arg.url + "\nAsync: " + arg.async + "\nData: " + arg.data + "\n");
    }
};

function Success(e)
{
alert(e);
retrun e;
}
```

**WithOut Callback**: you dont need to return any data

```
var ajax = function (arg) {
if (typeof arg.method !== "undefined" && typeof arg.url !== "undefined" && typeof arg.async !== "undefined" 
    && typeof arg.success !== "undefined" && typeof arg.data !== "undefined") {
    var xmlhttp, i = 0,
    versions = [
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0",
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0",   
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",  
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",   
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",  
        "Microsoft.XmlHttp"
    ];

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        for ( ; i < versions.length; i++) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]); break;
            } catch (e) { }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

            } else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                console.log("There was an error 400");
            } else {
                console.log("UNSUCCESSFUL");
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open(arg.method, arg.url, arg.async);
    xmlhttp.send(arg.data);
    console.log("Method: " + arg.method + "\nURL: " + arg.url + "\nAsync: " + arg.async + "\nData: " + arg.data + "\n");
}
};
```